# Headphones not working on Ubuntu 16.04 installed on Alienware 17 R3

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

I own a Sony MDR-XB450 headphones and it is not being detected. Sound keeps playing through external speakers

Alsamixer gives the details as below
Card: HDA Intel PCH
Chip: Creative CA0132
I can mute/unmute Hp/speaker and hp/speaker autodetect, no use

Any help regarding this would be appreaciated. Output of Alsa info is given below

http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=eab9df3cd1fbe887705f41603d8d9cc2c2833911

Thanks a lot